# Return only created subdocument mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to push a new document into an array and use his _id.

Right now im using findOneAndUpdate, i know i can use { new: true } but i only need the created document and not the parent document.

this is my code so far

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        'posts._id': req.params.id
    },
    {
        $push: {
            'posts.$.comments': {
                from: {
                    _id: req.user._id,
                    username: req.user.username,
                },
                body: req.body.commentBody
            }
        }
    },
    err => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        // Do something with ObjectId
    }
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to rephrase your question. Whats the issue here? What do you mean by "I only need the created document and not the parent document"? What do you mean by "use his _id"? Do you just want to store `_id` in this document?

Comment: i have a comments array, the code above create a comment document and insert it into the comments array, now i need to get the new _id of the new comment document that i just created, i hope i explained it right

Comment: I think the callback returns the new document. You just have to 
 use`doc.comments[doc.comments.length]._id`

Comment: ^ but this is only if you are have nested schemas and are not just storing the subdocument as JSON object. You should put the Comment's model in the Schema of the post.

Comment: posts is an array too so we need to know in what index the post is, the doc is like this doc.posts[postIndex].comments[commentIndex] thats why i wanted to get only the created document and not the whole document

Comment: no i just find it by this code {
        'posts._id': req.params.id
    }

Comment: you could use `doc.posts.find` and get the post that matches the `_id`. But this would be bit of processing on node itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169460/discussion-between-dushyant-bangal-and-asaf-aviv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findOneAndUpdate` callback gives you the updated document.

You have the Post's `_id`. You can use that to find the post to which you are adding the comment to. As you are pushing the comment, it will be the last element in the post array.

```
var mypost = doc.posts.find(function(post){
    return post._id.toString()==req.params.id
});

console.log(mypost.comments[mypost.comments.length]._id)
```

Comment: To answer your question about a possible issue if two comments come at same time - I dont think so (though I'm not 100% sure). Even if they come at same time, mongo will update the document one by one and return one by one. Even if it doesn't get executed in sequence (B then A), you will still get the doc with B and then A in their respective callbacks. I dont think it will update the doc with B and A both and send that doc to both of the call backs